# Add product variations programmatically via specific data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

What i am trying to do is save a new variation but when saving it, it throws an error
Call to a member function get_name() on string;
The variations are being created but without any attribute value.

```
public static function create_product_variants($id,$product,$variant_data){
        
        for($i=0; $i< count($variant_data); $i++){
            $variant = new WC_Product_Variation();
            $variant->set_parent_id($id);
            
            foreach($variant_data[$i] as $key => $value){
                if($key == 'attribute_name'){
                    $attribute_name = $value;
                }
                if($key == 'variant'){
                    if(gettype($value) == 'string'){
                        $variants = [$value];
                    }else{
                        $variants = $value;
                    }   
                }
            }
            if(count($variants) == count($attribute_name)){
                $variant_attributes = array();
            
                for($j=0; $j< count($variants); $j++){
                    $variant_attributes[$attribute_name[$j]] = $variants[$j];
                }
                $variant->set_attributes($variant_attributes);
            }
            $id = $variant->save();
            
        }
}
```

The data passing through `$variant_data` is like:

```
[
    {
      attribute_name: ["Color","Size"]
      price: "10"
      quantity: "20"
      variant: ["red","24"]
    }
]
```

`$id` is product_id

Comment: The code you have shown in your question doesn't call `get_name` anywhere. That means that the error is triggered somewhere within the variant code. Can you please check which exact file and line it refers to? You should also see a stack trace telling you which part of your code triggered this process that leads to the error.

Comment: yes i have checked that thing and i know where the error has been triggered but what i can understand is some value isn't passing to that place from the function given above

Comment: Well, that's exactly the kind of information we need to help you. Identify which command in your function started this whole thing so that we can help you determine what is being passed wrong.

Comment: `$variant->set_attributes($variant_attributes);` this is the place which i feel is causing problem.

Comment: You shouldn't have to guess which part causes it. The error stack trace should show you exactly what was called and in which order.

Comment: yes i got the place where its showing error, but i really cant get it fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some complications and mistakes in your code. Instead try the following revisited code:

```
public static function create_product_variants( $id, $product, $data ){
    foreach( $data as $variation_data ){
        if( isset($variation_data['attribute_name']) && isset($variation_data['variant']) ){
            $variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
            
            $variation->set_parent_id($id); // Set parent ID
            
            $variation->set_regular_price($variation_data['price']); // Set price
            $variation->set_price($variation_data['price']); // Set price
            
            // Enable and set stock
            if ( isset($variation_data['quantity']) ) {
                $variation->set_manage_stock(true);
                $variation->set_stock_quantity($variation_data['quantity']);
                $variation->set_stock_status('instock');
            }
            
            $attributes      = array(); // Initializing
            $attribute_names = (array) $variation_data['attribute_name'];
            $attribute_terms = (array) $variation_data['variant']; 
        
            // Formatting attributes data array
            foreach( $attribute_names as $key => $attribute_name ){
                $attributes[sanitize_title($attribute_name)] = $attribute_terms[$key];
            }
            
            $variation->set_attributes($attributes); // Set attributes
            $variation_id = $variation->save(); // Save to database (return the variation Id)
        }
    }
}
```

It should better work.

The variations will be created/saved, the the method `get_name()` should not throw any error this time.

Comment: its working now but its not setting the variation term

Comment: Sir,I found the fix and have made changes to your answer, strtolower() to the attribute name

Comment: @VardanaBhanot Better use `sanitize_title()` instead, than `strtolower()`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it simple like

```
public static function create_product_variants($id,$product,$variant_data){
        
    foreach ($variant_data as $object){
        $variant = new WC_Product_Variation();
        $variant->set_parent_id($product->get_id());
        $attributes = array_combine($object->attribute_name, $object->variant)
        $variant->set_attributes($attributes);
        $variant->save();
    }
    
}
```

if the object is

```
[
    {
      attribute_name: ["Color","Size"]
      price: "10"
      quantity: "20"
      variant: ["red","24"]
    }
]
```

Comment: I made the changes still I am getting the same problem, and i guess for each can iterate over objects so that shouldn't affect it.

Comment: You're only setting the first attribute. Your code doesn't account for a dynamic number of them.

Comment: The question changes all the time and the object has changed structure. I updated the code

Comment: `$object->attribute_name` with this i cant access the element of array inside the object value.

Comment: _"The question changes all the time and the object has changed structure."_ - what? The question was edited only once, and it was only formatting that has changed. Nothing in the comments suggests that the code might be different than presented.